# Binding winform control property in XAML

Tags: wpf, data-binding

We are currently in the process of switching our product from WinForms to WPF. At the moment we are using some 3rd party WinForm controls that are required for our application. Even though we plan to eventually replace them with WPF versions, right now this is not possible. We've tried hosting them in the wpf window inside WindowsFormsHost control, and it seems to work just fine. The only problem we have is how to pass our data from VM to these controls. We would like to avoid any code-behind and alterations to VM just to accomodate this controls. Ideally, we would prefer to keep VM completely unaware of the controls used to display it's data, so that when we do change to WPF version of these controls, we only need to modify the view. This is why we're looking for a way to bind VM property to hosted WinForm control from XAML. If this helps, we can certainly live with the fact that there is only a one way binding from VM to the control, and we don't mind if the binding works only once, without the subsequent updates from VM, since the VM properties we are binding do not change. Perhaps someone has any ideas how we can make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if there is a better way, but here's one idea:

Wrap your WinForm control/WindowsFormsHost control into a wrapper control (inherit from Control or use a UserControl, whatever is best for you).

On this wrapper you can add dependency properties that you want to bind to your VM.

Inside the wrapper code, you can add the boilerplate required to propagate changes back and forth between your wrapper dependency properties and your winform properties.

This hides the dirt under the carpet and exposes a nice WPF facade that you can bind to as usual, without changing your VM.

When the control is phased out, remove the wrapper from your project and you can bind the VM directly to the new WPF replacement control.

Comment: +1, though some code samples would make this a better answer.